# Why does Javascript use JSON.stringify instead of JSON.serialize?

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering about *"stringify"* vs *"serialize"*. To me they're the same thing (though I could be wrong), but in my past experience (mostly with [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)) I use `Serialize()` and never use `Stringify()`.

I know I can create a simple alias in Javascript,

```
// either
JSON.serialize = function(input) {
    return JSON.stringify(input);
};

// or
JSON.serialize = JSON.stringify;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HKKUb/

but I'm just wondering about the difference between the two and why stringify was chosen.

---

for comparison purpose, here's how you serialize XML to a String in C#

```
public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
    StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
    return textWriter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Actually can't you just do `JSON.serialize = JSON.stringify`?

Comment: why yes you can.

Comment: I suppose after re-reading my question, I'm seeing that in my C# example, I'm serializing the XML and THEN converting the serialized object `ToString();`. There inlies the rub.

Comment: I guess for continuity, it would be better (for me) to have a method that looks like this... `JSON.serialize(obj).toString();` or `jsonObject().toString();`... this way it would look much like my C#... but now I'm over complicating it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a closer look at the two comments you've put onto the question:

> I suppose after re-reading my question, I'm seeing that in my C#
>   example, I'm serializing the XML and THEN converting the serialized
>   object ToString();. There inlies the rub.

and

> I guess for continuity, it would be better (for me) to have a method
>   that looks like this... JSON.serialize(obj).toString(); or
>   jsonObject().toString();... this way it would look much like my C#...
>   but now I'm over complicating it.

Now remember that in Javascript, an object is a hash (rather, if using Prototype or another framework, it should be qualified as a "special kind of hash" - but the simple form works for this example):

```
var obj = {
   foo: 1,
   bar: function() { console.log(this.foo); }
}
obj.foo; // 1
obj.bar; // function reference
obj.bar(); // function call
obj['foo']; // 1
obj['bar']; // function reference
obj['bar'](); // function call
```

The only reason a `serialize()` might be necessary in Javascript is to cut out the functions, references to other objects, etc.

So, to go back to your C# example - we've just cut out `.Serialize()` as unnecessary.  An object is a hash, it's already serialized, further "serialization" would have to be done manually in your own code anyway.  All that leaves you is `.ToString()`.

Does `.stringify()` make more sense now?

Comment: yes, stringify makes sense, however I'd still rather use `.toString()`

Comment: toString could mean anything.  JSON.stringify is clearly JSON.

Answer (score 12):

This is because that [JSON](http://www.json.org) notation was specified in 1999 not after [2002](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) (`asp.net` is released at that year). so i guess they didn't know about the `serialize`.

Jokes apart,

Hearing the word `serialization`, first thing that comes to my mind is  like converting the data to bytes, here JSON.stringify makes perfect sense as it converts the object to a string representation not a byte representation.

PS:

@Chase Florell, you can't just add `JSON.serialize`, as in strict mode, this code may actually fail in some browsers.

as `JSON` is not your average Object.

Comment: I guess in my (limited) experience, serializing something has always been converting it to some form of string for flat file storage. I get what you're saying though.

Comment: I thought it was 2001.. see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). The name was probably a personal preference of Douglas Crockford. 1999 is the year the 3rd ECMA standard came out, on which JSON is founded.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell serializing just literally refers to turning an in memory object into a serially contiguous data format so it may be atomically contained, I believe a more common method of doing it would be the bytewise representation, for sending across networks or other such.

Comment: @avinashr, re: your *ps:* edit... [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7pw5/1/) doesn't seem to fail. can you explain how "`JSON` is not your average Object"? I'm not being snarky, just unclear on what you mean.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell is correct - with regards to Javascript, JSON is a _subset_ of valid Javascript objects.  See my answer for a simple example:  All valid JSON is a valid Javascript object/hash, but not all Javascript object/hashes are valid JSON.   It's even in the name - JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation".

Comment: @ChaseFlorell i've seen in IE, that under strict mode, it sometimes doesn't allow you to mutate one object if it is set as a Read-Only object. (like `console` object). So i referred that to say that "`JSON is not your average object`". So it may not be so good to change it as your code may fail in different implementations. If i'm wrong, please let me know. thanks,See also [MSDN on strict mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230269%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. IE pretty much breaks everything for everyone ;-)